# Yii2 CKEditor allow to use only one font

Tags: yii2, ckeditor

I have a CKeditor widget ([this one](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget)) installed on my Yii2 site, and I want to allow my visitors to use only one font when they adding messages using this widget. For example, now in my widget I have a selection of fonts, but I want to block them all except one. For example, in this picture, you can see my CKEditor panel with the "Fonts" dropdown opened:
[image]
As you can see, I have some fonts for select (Arial, Comic Sanc etc). I want to remove all of them except one.
Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I've found the answer - you can change the fonts allowed to use by this widget in the ckeditor.js file, using the "CKEDITOR.config.font_names" variable. It's better not to change this file directly, but to add the "CKEDITOR.config.font_names" variable to the config.js file and to change it there.